# Правильное написание своих функций в Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Как правильно, по-laravelовски, определять свои функции для работы с ними в контроллере?

Просто определять новые методы в контроллере и работать с ними? Или же делать отдельный класс со static методами? И, если класс, то как правильно его задать? Имеется ввиду, где сохранить, нужно ли регистрировать в провайдере или просто использовать use?

Comment: Зависит от сложности проекта - а надо ли оно вообще. По REST в контроллере должны быть только определенные методы, список есть в вики, если есть возможность  создать еще один контроллер, то надо создать его, если метод специфический, можно его создать в этом же контроллере, или вынести в какой-то сервис. Нет четкого принципа - как сделаешь так и будет

Answer (score 2):

Вся логика логика распологается в [сервис контейнерах](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/container), для обращения к ним можно сделать [фасады](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/facades)